# How do I limit the properties of a query based of a common subproperty?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Given the schema:

```
{
  _id: ObjectID,
  city: 
   { units: 
      { abc: {},
        def: { tuid : String },
        ...
        xxx: { tuid : String }
   }
}
```

I would like to return, for a particular `_id`, all the properties of `units` who's subproperty `tuid` is, for example, 123.

I have searched for information about this but array operations keep popping up instead of what I need.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do it in a general way, you need to explicitly include each tuid path using dot notation.

Comment: Then I would need to group them by tuid when adding them but this would cause problems for other operations. Would some sort of aggregation help? @JohnnyHK